# Argparse + cmd2 RecursionError even on simple programs

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, argparse, cmd2

Sample code:

```
import argparse
import cmd2
import sys


def create_subparser(a_parser = None):
    if a_parser is None:
        new_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    else:
        new_parser = a_parser.add_parser("single")
    new_parser.add_argument("--single-param", "-sp")
    return new_parser


def single_print(some_param):
    print("single operation " + str(some_param))


def other_print():
    print("other operation")


class TestCmd(cmd2.Cmd):
    single_parser = create_subparser()

    @cmd2.with_argparser(single_parser)
    def do_single(self, opts):
        print(opts)
        single_print(opts.single_param)

    def do_other(self, opts):
        other_print()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help="commands", dest="mode")
    create_subparser(subparsers)
    cmd_parser = subparsers.add_parser("cmd", help="shell")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.mode == "single":
        single_print(args.single_param)
    else:
        sys.argv = [sys.argv[0]]  # cmd2 complains about unknown parameters without
        cmd = TestCmd()
        cmd.cmdloop()
```

In the example, I'm trying to make a program that can either run in single mode (`program.py single -sp test`) or in cmd/prompt mode (`program.py cmd`), which then would call single mode or other operation (inside the shell, write `single -sp test` or `other`. Anyway, if I try to get all the values for the argparse being used in the do_single inside the cmd2 class, I get `EXCEPTION of type 'RecursionError' occurred with message: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison'`. Using cmd2's debug, it goes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/.../site-packages/cmd2/cmd2.py", line 2011, in onecmd_plus_hooks
    stop = self.onecmd(statement, add_to_history=add_to_history)
  File "/home/.../site-packages/cmd2/cmd2.py", line 2441, in onecmd
    stop = func(statement)
  File "/home/.../site-packages/cmd2/decorators.py", line 308, in cmd_wrapper
    return func(*args_list, **kwargs)
  File "test.py", line 28, in do_single
    print(opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/argparse.py", line 131, in __repr__
    arg_strings.append('%s=%r' % (name, value))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/argparse.py", line 131, in __repr__
    arg_strings.append('%s=%r' % (name, value))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/argparse.py", line 131, in __repr__
    arg_strings.append('%s=%r' % (name, value))
  [Previous line repeated 326 more times]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/argparse.py", line 129, in __repr__
    for name, value in self._get_kwargs():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/argparse.py", line 139, in _get_kwargs
    return sorted(self.__dict__.items())
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

The reason I'm using the `create_subparser` function is because I'm creating the subparsers to be used by the cmd2.Cmd subclass, but I want to use the same parser for the modes when invoked from the main shell. This is basically a minimum working example, my code has a lot more flags and whatnot.

One other thing, the problem seems to happen because of `print(opts)`. It seems it tries to do `vars(opts)` and when it tries enumerating all the variables, it runs out of memory due to recursion somewhere. If I don't try to list all the variables inside the object (for example, if I used just `opts.single_param`), it would work. It seems to be related to me trying to use the same argparser both inside cmd2 and with the main program, but I don't understand why exactly it's happening and if it can be fixed.

Comment: Had to read and follow your code.  It does look like `opts` is a recursively defined `Namespace` object, but I have no idea how it was produced.  I wonder if `print(vars(opts))` works any better.

Comment: `(vars(opts))` seems to cause the issue in the first place. I believe it's called in the method to convert to string once I try to print. So it's not any different.

Answer (score 0):

Without `cmd2` I can't run your code.  But I can make a namespace that exhibits your problem.

```
In [429]: ns = argparse.Namespace(foo='bar', baz=12)                                                 
In [430]: ns.ns = ns                                                                                 
In [431]: print(ns)                                                                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-431-0769451eb86e> in <module>
----> 1 print(ns)

/usr/lib/python3.6/argparse.py in __repr__(self)
    133         for name, value in self._get_kwargs():
    134             if name.isidentifier():
--> 135                 arg_strings.append('%s=%r' % (name, value))
    136             else:
    137                 star_args[name] = value

... last 1 frames repeated, from the frame below ...

/usr/lib/python3.6/argparse.py in __repr__(self)
    133         for name, value in self._get_kwargs():
    134             if name.isidentifier():
--> 135                 arg_strings.append('%s=%r' % (name, value))
    136             else:
    137                 star_args[name] = value

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

You could test the individual attributes until you find the one that's the problem:

```
In [432]: list(ns.__dict__.keys())                                                                   
Out[432]: ['foo', 'baz', 'ns']
```